# Error while executing transactions in Ionic 2 app using Sqlite from Ionic Native

Tags: sqlite, cordova, angular, transactions, ionic2

I have a project wherein I have a service for setting up and querying local sqlite database. I'm using cordova-sqlite-plugin and Sqlite from Ionic Native.

This is the code I have to open the database and create tables once the database is opened.

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {SQLite} from "ionic-native";

@Injectable()
export class LocalDbService {

sqlDb: SQLite;

constructor() {
    this.sqlDb = new SQLite();
}

openDatabase() {
    return this.sqlDb.openDatabase({
        name: 'app.db',
        location: 'default'
    }).then(() => {
        return this.sqlDb.transaction((tx) => {
            tx.executeSql(`create table if not exists groups (
              id nvarchar(50) primary key not null,
              name nvarchar(50) unique not null,
              createdOn datetime not null default current_timestamp,
              updatedOn datetime not null default current_timestamp,
              deleted boolean not null default 0
            )`, [])
        })
    }).catch((err) => {
      console.error('Error while creating tables', err);
    })
}
}
```

The database opens correctly. But, the problem is that the transaction to create the tables always throws an error. In the catch phase when I log the error, it is always undefined.

If I execute a simple executeSql method instead of a transaction, it runs fine. I'm currently running the code on Android 6.0 based device.

I've read the following documentation of [sql transactions](https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage#sql-transactions) in Cordova sqlite plugin and the documentation of Sqlite plugin in Ionic native.

What is the correct way to use Sqlite transactions with Ionic 2?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are getting error because you are not able to access `this.sqlDb` inside `then` you can try with below if `openDatabase` is returning promise with reference to your opened database :

```
this.sqlDb.openDatabase({
    name: 'app.db',
    location: 'default'
}).then((db) => {
    return db.transaction((tx) => {
        tx.executeSql(`create table if not exists groups (
          id nvarchar(50) primary key not null,
          name nvarchar(50) unique not null,
          createdOn datetime not null default current_timestamp,
          updatedOn datetime not null default current_timestamp,
          deleted boolean not null default 0
        )`, [])
    })
}).catch((err) => {
  console.error('Error while creating tables', err);
});
```

Or if `openDatabase` is not returning promise then you have to create transaction after creating db by checking if db is opened or not like:

```
this.sqlDb.openDatabase({
    name: 'app.db',
    location: 'default'
});
if(this.sqlDb) { 
    this.sqlDb.transaction((tx) => {
        tx.executeSql(`create table if not exists groups (
            id nvarchar(50) primary key not null,
            name nvarchar(50) unique not null,
            createdOn datetime not null default current_timestamp,
            updatedOn datetime not null default current_timestamp,
            deleted boolean not null default 0
        )`, [])
    });
}
```

Comment: this.sqlDb is definitely available inside the promise-> then portion as I'm using arrow functions. I even checked it by logging it out. It runs methods apart from transaction properly. It only throws error when I call the transaction method. This behaviour is not only inside the openDatabase promise. Anywhere I use it, it throws an error when using transaction. Thanks for helping out.

Comment: same behaviour do I have in my project. somehow transactions dont work how they should.